# How can I construct a vim keymapping that inserts the current date?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, vimrc

I'm trying to create a vim keymapping that will initiate the creation of a new file, with the name of the file prefixed with the current date, waiting for me to finish typing the filename.

Put more precisely, I want to hit `<Leader>n`, and have vim enter for me in the command line:

`:new 2014-08-05-` ... waiting for me to complete the filename and hit `<CR>`.

How can I do this? I've tried this, but it didn't do quite what I expected, as it just echo-ed the date. How can I get vim to dynamically insert characters into the command line? Am I missing something simple?

```
function! NewNotesFile()
    echon ":new " . strftime("%F")
endfunction

nnoremap <Leader>n :call NewNotesFile()<CR>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two ways. You can just insert the result of an expression to the command-line via `:help c_CTRL-R`:

```
:nnoremap <Leader>n :new <C-r>=strftime('%F')<CR>
```

This mapping mirrors how you would do it interactively. Alternatively, you can evaluate the right-hand side of the mapping via a `:help map-expr`:

```
:nnoremap <expr> <Leader>n ':new ' . strftime('%F')
```

Comment: Hello. I tried the first, but it doesn't quite work. I should have been clearer; I *don't* want to insert the <CR>, as I want to leave the cursor in place to finish off the filename manually. But when I remove it, it just opens a command-line and inserts the literal text `=strftime('%F')`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The second doesn't work either; I just get the error "Unknown mark".

Comment: Correction, the second does work; I made a typo.

Comment: I've considered that (in the first mapping, too); the `<CR>` is just to conclude the `<C-r>=` expression. Try it out!

Comment: Huh. Just tried the first one again and it worked this time. I guess I'm just typo-prone. Sorry! Thanks for the help in figuring this out, I just learnt about <expr> in mappings :)

Answer (score 3):

Using `c_CTRL-\_e` (it’s a help tag, so see `:h c_CTRL-\_e` if something seems unclear) for instance:

```
nnoremap <Leader>n :<C-\>e"new " . strftime("%F")<CR>
```

Comment: I find @Ingo Karkat's second example slightly clearer, but this definitely works too, thanks.